# xmlHttp call does not work in IE11 (Cross Doamin Issue?)

Tags: windows, web-services, cordova, xmlhttprequest, internet-explorer-11

We are developing a Windows Store Apps using Apache Cordova. In this application, we are making some web service calls to another Cloud CRM system using XMLHttpRequest. It works fine when we test it in Android, but the same results in error when we run it in Windows 8.1. The call is successfully made via send() method, but the response has no data (ended in error, but no clear and helpful error message). It seems to be some problems with the request made across domain. Can you please help us in resolving this issue? Thanks a lot in advance for your time and support.

Comment: You should add the code and the full error to your question. There's not enough here for us to confirm the issue, let alone solve it. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your Cloud CRM's URI is white listed and this guide is followed:

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide